# how to fix "Error: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc inv"?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

My question is a little different from those already posted because i am only using Numpy on python2.
And i get this error:

> A_inv = np.linalg.inv(A)   File
> "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 551, in
> inv
> ainv = _umath_linalg.inv(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj) TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was
> found for ufunc inv

Her is my code:

```
A = np.array([[r, -s],
              [b,-1]])
# Constant matrix
B = np.array([-z, -a])

# Equations being solved
print("Equations being solved:")
print("rd - sk = -z")
print("db - k = -a")


# Finding the inverse of matrix A
A_inv = np.linalg.inv(A)

# Solving for the variables
X = np.dot(A_inv, B)

# Printing the solution
print("The solution is:")
print("k = "+repr(X[0]))
print("d = "+repr(X[1]))
```

And for reference r,s,z are very big numbers.

Comment: Show `A` and `A.dtype`

Comment: The error message you're encountering suggests that there's an issue with the data type or shape mismatch when attempting to use the inv function from NumPy's linear algebra module. Here are a few suggestions: 1.Ensure that the variables r, s, z, a, and b are all of the appropriate numeric types. If one of these is a different type, you could encounter unexpected issues. 2.The matrix A might be singular. In this case, attempting to find its inverse will result in an error. You can check the determinant of the matrix before inverting it. If the determinant is zero, then the matrix is singular.

Comment: a = 4, b= 13, r,s,z are of type Long because they big numbers like 30 decimal digits

Comment: Please *link* to any question that you've already posted so we can find out about the history.